# PhantomJS AWS Browser Tab Title

Tags: pdf, phantomjs

I have a problem with my browser tab title.

Actually on my website I generate some report using PhantomJS and pull them on a AWS S3 Bucket. I access to them using some link like that : http://192.168.33.120/report/8/1?export=inline

The problem is that my Browser tab titles are like : 1 or 1?export=inline, it display the url and not my PDF file name.

Is that possible using PhantomJS to set a property like title or other think like that to specify the title that I want to show on browser view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title of the rendered PDF cannot be explicitly set. `document.title` is also not used for the PDF title. Although, [qpdfwriter.h has a `setTitle` function](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/2.0.0/src/qt/qtbase/src/gui/painting/qpdfwriter.h#L67). You can issue a feature-request on GitHub to expose this function if you like.

You can also simply name your reports appropriately by selecting good URLs. That way the PDF title will be a non-issue.