# Change document properties of PDF using PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs

Can we change document properties of the generated PDF using PhantomJS? I would like to change the PDF producer settings.

I am currently using phantomjs-1.9.8.

Comment: I am not sure but try these links. It might help - https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf, http://www.feedhenry.com/server-side-pdf-generation-node-js/

Comment: @LittlePanda - thanks for your answer. That had very useful information, but I will not be able to change PDF document properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that with vanilla PhantomJS. You will have to adjust the code and recompile. See for example something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28727205).

Comment: B - thanks for your repsonse.  think I will not be able to change PDF producer value.